# Как открыть .py файл через Python

Tags: python

начал изучать Python , остановился в самом начале.
В книге от меня требуется следующее:

Создадим файл программы Python и запустим его.

1. Откройте текстовый редактор.
2. Введите в него строку print(27), как это показано здесь.
3. Сохраните этот файл с именем test.py. Убедитесь, что вы сохранили его как
   простой текст, а не в формате вроде RTF или DOC. Вы не обязаны использовать
   расширение .py для файлов программ Python, но оно поможет вам запомнить
   предназначение файла
4. Если вы пользуетесь графическим пользовательским интерфейсом — это касается
   практически каждого, — откройте окно терминала1
   .
5. Запустите программу, введя следующую строку:
   $ python test.py
   Вы должны увидеть такую строку:
   27

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очевидно, вы открыли командную строку не в той папке

Comment: набери сначала ``cd "C:\IT Project"``, чтобы перейти в нужную папку

Comment: C:\IT Project>python test.py
python: can't open file 'C:\\IT Project\\test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\IT Project>

Comment: C:\Users\rusla>python
Python 3.11.2 (tags/v3.11.2:878ead1, Feb  7 2023, 16:38:35) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Comment: похоже, что вы сняли или не поставили галочку "add to path" при установке `Python`

Comment: Переустанавливал с  python.org, обязательно проверял наличие галочки

Comment: Имя вашего файла не `test.py`, а `test.py.txt` — вы сохранили его с неправильным расширением, а в Проводнике расширение `.txt` скрыто

Comment: Все работает, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Просто набери сначала cd и путь к папке в которой лежит этот файлможно просто перетащить папку в терминал и путь к папке сам напишется